# How do you ask someone to input the values of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, input-forms

I'm trying to set up code that basically asks the user to input the values of a matrix with a certain key size. I want them to first enter the keysize and then ask for all of the entries necessary to fill the square matrix of that keysize.

Comment: Mathematica has already provided means to input a matrix. See e.g. 
 https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InputAMatrix.html

Comment: After you ask for the matrix size, you could present a [TableView](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableView.html) using the matrix size for the `AllowedDimensions` option.

Comment: Maybe one could used FormFunction, although it seem to be designed more for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. This Code may help you prepare your input boxes.

```
Panel[
country = 0;
sector = 0;
level = 0;
result = {};
While[Not[IntegerQ[country] && 1 <= country <= 64], (country = Input["Which country do you want to analyze?"])];
While[Not[IntegerQ[sector] && 1 <= sector <= 15], (sector = Input["Which sector do you want to target?"])];
While[Not[NumericQ[level] && 0.01 <= level <= 1], (level = Input["At what significance level do you want to analyze IO matrix?"])];
result = {country, sector, level};
If[
 result === {}, "", result
 ]
]
```

Comment: This hangs up Mma 12.2.0-Win7x64 and the dialog wouldn't go away. Perhaps it is a version related artifact. There is a comma flagged in red in the `If` statement at the end.

Comment: is `result === {}, "",` to be `result === {}, "", result` ?

Comment: @AsukaMinato: Yes, you are right, however, for some reason, the dialogue box does not go away as noted by Syed noted. I cannot find the reason for that.